# Add a popup button or icon that allow to open external website in Sencha 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I want to add some function or icon when I click on it opens new poup of that website link in that poup.How can I add it.

```
    {
        xtype: "list",
        store: "Plays",
        itemId:"playsList",
        loadingText: "Loading PlaysList...",
        emptyText: '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No PlayList found.</div>',
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        draggable:true,
        itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{duration}</div><div class="list-item-hide">{hidden}</div>',
                  },
```

I want to add before onItemDisclosure button ie => I given details below of it.So when I click it open that particular website in Pop-Up

Output on Screen is like this

http://www.something.com 16 => 
http://www.some.com      18 =>

Comment: Please refer and describe your device to using on question. View details here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @hekomobile Sorry I didn't knew.Thanks for knowing all faq :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps. :)

```
var outerPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    style: {
        background:'#ffffff',
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'click to open', 
            handler:function() {
                var overlay = new Ext.Panel({
                    floating : true,
                    modal:true,
                    centered : true,
                    width : 700,
                    height : 500,
                    styleHtmlContent: true, 
                    html: '<div><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://www.some.com/">Your device does not support iframes.</iframe></div>',
                    items: [],
                }).show('pop', true);
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

[image]

**Ciao**

Comment: i dont want to open a iframe here i want to display one form in the popup. so what changes i have to do